# Conjugate element

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a group of order $2014$. Let $\theta\in G$ such that $|\theta|=19$ and $\alpha\in G$ such that $|\alpha|=2$. Show that $\alpha\theta\alpha=\theta^{\pm1}$.
Since the order of $\alpha$ is 2 I know that $\alpha=\alpha^{-1}$ so $\alpha\theta\alpha=\alpha^{-1}\theta\alpha$ so the element is conjugate to $\theta$ and thas must be $\theta^x$ for some positive integer x such that $0<x<19$ (I already showed that the group generated by $\theta$ is a unique sylow-p group in $G$). I would like a hint on how to continue from here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: What is the group of automorphims of $\mathbb Z/19\mathbb Z$? (Or at least: What is the order of it?)

> There are $18$ automorphisms of $\mathbb Z/19\mathbb Z$: for $1\le k\le 18$ we obtain one from $1\mapsto k$. Among these is $x\mapsto x^{-1}$, which is of order $2$ and (because $18=2\cdot 9$) is the *only* automorphism of order $2$. Since conjugation with $\alpha$ is an automorphism of order at most $2$, the claim follows.

Comment: Can you explain why the order of this automorphism is exactly 2?

Comment: @Gyt because the inverse of the inverse is the element itself (and because some elements are note their own inverses)

Comment: von Etzen And why is it the only automorphism?